# map $Id in web api to custom id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a DTO with a custom Id like SomeId. A get request returns return JSON in this format:

```
... "$id":"2","SomeId":1 ...
```

Can I somehow map SomeId to  $Id before the ApiController action returns the JSON?

Comment: What do you mean by mapping? Do you mean replacing the values - replace *$id* value with value from *SomeId*?

Comment: Mapping in the sense of POCO to JSON ... => SomeId == $id

Comment: If you need to manipulate the POCO before returning it from your controller, why don't you just do it from within your controller method itself?

Comment: That does not make sense. I have no influence over $id - it is NOT part of the POCO which is serialized!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using the default JSON formatter (Json.NET) in ASP.NET Web API and what you see as `"$id"` is actually a reference used to preserve the handle so if the element repeats somewhere it wont repeat the data, it will just set a `"$ref"` property of the duplicate to the `"$id"` of the original.

What you can do to disable this is add the following code to **Application_Start** method in the **Global.asax** file:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

You can read more about this here:

- [Handling Circular Object References](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#handling_circular_object_references)
- [PreserveReferencesHandling setting](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm)